# Вставка видео с youtube

Tags: вёрстка, видео, youtube, youtube-api

Привет Всем!

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0hpzEGU0D5Y?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&playlist=0hpzEGU0D5Y&amp;disablekb=1"
                frameborder="0" gesture="media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Вставляю (без помощи JSa) в лендинг видео с youtubе, прописываю все настройки, но не могу найти как выключить звук? 
У юзера не будет возможности посмотреть на панель и выключить самому.

> **Вопрос: Как выключить звук? (желательно без использования js)**

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте к URL GET параметр **?mute=1**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VbCIbcv6gfw?mute=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```